# OKhttp как прикрепить cookie к запросу?

Tags: java, android, http, cookie

Есть такой вот POST запрос, и есть кука типа String "auth=wfgewg7f727fg27f2g72fg72"

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();



String post(String...url) throws IOException {
    //RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
    FormEncodingBuilder form = new FormEncodingBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i < url.length; i += 2) {
        form.add(url[i].toString(), url[i + 1].toString());
        }
    //System.out.println("form11 "+form);
    RequestBody formBody =form.build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url[0])
            .post(formBody)
            .build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body().string();
}
```

Вопрос: как приерепить куку к запросу, чтоб PHP сервер принял запрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кука передается через заголовки.

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .header("Cookie", "auth=wfgewg7f727fg27f2g72fg72")
        .url(url[0])
        .post(formBody)
        .build();
```

Посмотри еще на механизм интерсепторов https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors чтобы не делать эту руками на каждый запрос.