# Как прикрепить cookie к POST-запросу используя OkHttp и Retrofit2?

Tags: android, retrofit

Мне нужно обратиться к серверу через POST-запрос и передать ему в заголовок куки типа "auth_ses=gdfDgbrlee4g50". Т.к. Retrofit2 не отправляет куки, пришлось подключить OkHttp. Один из примеров отправки куков нашел по [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/440467/okhttp-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-cookie-%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83). Однако с библиотекой Retrofit2 (с первой не работал вовсе) работаю впервые и не знаю как правильно реализовать такую связку.

Answer (score 1):

1. > [android retrofit okhttp cookies](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20retrofit%20okhttp%20cookies)
2. [Handling Cookies with OkHttp/Retrofit](http://tsuharesu.com/handling-cookies-with-okhttp/):

А там такой код:

```
/**
 * This interceptor put all the Cookies in Preferences in the Request.
 * Your implementation on how to get the Preferences MAY VARY.
 * <p>
 * Created by tsuharesu on 4/1/15.
 */
public class AddCookiesInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();
        HashSet<String> preferences = (HashSet) Preferences.getDefaultPreferences().getStringSet(Preferences.PREF_COOKIES, new HashSet<>());
        for (String cookie : preferences) {
            builder.addHeader("Cookie", cookie);
            Log.v("OkHttp", "Adding Header: " + cookie); // This is done so I know which headers are being added; this interceptor is used after the normal logging of OkHttp
        }

        return chain.proceed(builder.build());
    }
}


/**
 * This Interceptor add all received Cookies to the app DefaultPreferences.
 * Your implementation on how to save the Cookies on the Preferences MAY VARY.
 * <p>
 * Created by tsuharesu on 4/1/15.
 */
public class ReceivedCookiesInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());

        if (!originalResponse.headers("Set-Cookie").isEmpty()) {
            HashSet<String> cookies = new HashSet<>();

            for (String header : originalResponse.headers("Set-Cookie")) {
              cookies.add(header);
            }

            Preferences.getDefaultPreferences().edit()
                    .putStringSet(Preferences.PREF_COOKIES, cookies)
                    .apply();
        }

        return originalResponse;
    }
}

/**
 * Somewhere you create a new OkHttpClient and use it on all your requests.
 */
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
okHttpClient.interceptors().add(new AddCookiesInterceptor());
okHttpClient.interceptors().add(new ReceivedCookiesInterceptor());
```